# Why am I getting some extra, weird characters when making a file from grep output?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I am doing a very basic command that never gave me trouble in the past, but is inexplicably returning undesired characters now.

I am in BASH on linux, and simply want to search through a directory and make a file containing filenames that match a pattern:

```
ls | grep "*.file_ID" > my_list.txt
```

...This works fine, and if I cat the data:

```
   cat my_list.txt
       seriesA.file_ID
       seriesB.file_ID
       seriesC.file_ID
```

However, when I try to feed this file into downstream processes, I keep getting a weird errors, as if the file isn't properly formatted as a list of file names. When I open the file in vim to reveal any unnecessary characters, I find the file actually looks like this:

```
vi my_list.txt

^[[00mseriesA.file_ID^[[00m
^[[00mseriesB.file_ID^[[00m
^[[00mseriesC.file_ID^[[00m
```

For some reason, every line is started and ended with the characters `^[[00m`. If I delete these characters, all of the downstream processes work fine. However, I need to have my scripts automatically make such a file list, so I can't keep going in and manually deleting these chars.

Does anyone know what is producing the `^[[00m` characters? I don't have any idea where they are coming from, and need a to be able to generate files without them.

Thanks!

Comment: try running the command without double quotes

Comment: I just tried using either single quotes, double quotes, or no quotes, and there is no difference

Comment: and if you try sh -c ls | grep *.file_ID > my_list

Comment: The ^[00m are escape codes to colorize the output of bash, it's strange that it shows up here. How are you connected? By terminal or remote?

Comment: SSH to a computing cluster  -  Also, I found a solution, but not an explanation. Using the command `ls | grep -Po "series[A-C].gtf" > my_list.txt` doesn't return any extra characters

Comment: Using Putty? You should be able to set your terminal settings.

Comment: Ok, when it works, it works. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
printf "%s\n" *.file_ID > my_list.txt
```

Comment: Or in the event of a large number of matching files that could overflow the command line, `find . -name '*.file_ID' > my_list.txt` (although, some extra work is needed to remove the leading './' that `find` will produce for each file).

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @Pumbaa80, the literal answer to the question is use `command ls`, but the sensible answer is "don't do that"

Comment: @glenn jackman, The question was "Why...". Can you explain the reason this happens so others can apply the general solution?

Comment: Most likely the `ls` command is actually an alias or function that adds the `--color` option. So the odd chars are actually terminal color codes. `ls` output is intended for human eyes, not as input to other programs.'

Answer (score 8):

Probably your `GREP_OPTIONS` environment variable contains `--color=always`, which causes the output to be stuffed with control characters, even when piped to a file.

Use `--color=auto` instead.

http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html

Even better, don't use `grep`:

```
ls *.file_ID > my_list.txt
```

Comment: Or, even better... `echo *.file_ID > ...`, or `for f in *.file_ID; do ...`.

Answer (score 2):

- usually it is automatically => `grep --color=auto`
- if it pipes into a csv file that looks like this `^[[00...^[[00m`
- you would have to type this in the terminal:
  `grep --color=auto "your regex" > example.csv`
- if you want it to be a permanent situation where you do not have to type "`--color=auto`" every time, type this in the terminal:
  `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'`

more info: 
https://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2007/10/grep-with-color-output.html

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of it (assuming GNU find and no directory traversing):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.file_ID" -printf "%f\n" > my_list.txt
```

Example:

```
~> ls *file_ID*
a.file_ID  b.file_ID  c.file_ID

~> find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.file_ID" -printf "%f\n" > my_list.txt

~> cat my_list.txt
a.file_ID
b.file_ID
c.file_ID
```

As far as the "^[[00m" characters, check your ls options:

```
~> alias -p | grep "ls="
```

You may get something like:

```
alias ls='/bin/ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

If so, check env for this:

```
~> env | grep LS_OP
LS_OPTIONS=-N --color=tty -T 0
```

The character string you're referencing is used to turn off colors, so your shell likely has been set to show colors. Removing and/or changing the ls alias should resolve it.

Comment: You're right, the extra characters are not produced by `grep`, but by `ls`, which is why there is no problem with `grep -o` (as per the comments above)

Answer (score 0):

The weird characters such as `^[[00m` are escape characters for colorizing the output. Color output for `ls` is most likely enabled through an alias in your environment.

To avoid getting these color characters, you can try disable the `ls` alias temporarily with a backslash:

```
\ls *.txt
```

Or you can use `printf` command instead.

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt
```